# Running Jetty 7 server in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jetty

I'm trying to set up Eclipse to run and deploy my projects to a Jetty 7 server (the oldest version available from http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/).  I've downloaded Jetty 7 and unpacked it, and I've installed the Jetty plugin from the available server adapters list, but when I try to configure a new Jetty server, the server type list only contains "Jetty 6".  If I use this and point it at my server runtime, when I try to start it I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/start/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.start.Main
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

I'm guessing I need a different adaptor to start Jetty 7, but I have no idea where to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the package name changed with the migration to Eclipse, and the Jetty folks are still busy.

Your easiest option is to download Jetty 6 from Codehaus (http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/), unpack it somewhere and use the Jetty 6 adapter.

Comment: Kind-of ironic that the move to being an official eclipse project has made it *harder* to use Jetty with eclipse, but it does appear to be the case.  Oh well, back to v6 I guess. :(

Comment: ørn: What version is the new adapter, and where did you get it? I have org.mortbay.jetty.serveradaptor_1.0.4 (which was installed using "Download additional server adapters, and which is also available at http://www.webtide.com/eclipse/ ) With that adapter, Eclipse only offers me the runtime type "Jetty 6", and if I try to use it with Jetty 7, I get the same exception as in the question above.

Comment: @Chris, it's been a while.  I believe I downloaded it from the Eclipse marketplace.

Comment: I just found it: I followed the link from @Thomas Broyer's answer below. I had seen that site before, but it links to http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-wtp , which is unfortunately `404 File not found`. However, I just discovered that the development version at http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-wtp/development/ is still there. (Note, that "**org.eclipse**.jst.server.jetty.feature_1.0.0" contains the Jetty 7/8 adapters, while "**org.mortbay**.jetty.serveradaptor_1.0.4" does not!) Maybe somebody knows an updated link to a stable version of that plugin?

Comment: I've just burned a few hours trying to move from jetty-6 to a later eclipse-hosted version (7 or 8). Missing parts, missing documentation, "Just download and mvn install! with avail downloads missing pom.xml files, broken maven installs, missing documentation, broken links, "download through eclipse!". Seems like there's already a well-supported ecosystem for downloading and installing projects and this is needlessly, pointlessly complicated, as attested to by all of the questions/responses here for something that doesn't need to be complicated.

Answer (score 22):

Better than using the WTP adapters I prefer to use an embedded jetty.
I just create a regular java project, let's call "embedded-jetty". I make the original webapp project a requirement to this project in the Projects section of the 
Java Build Path of the project properties. Than I create a class that start a jetty instance like this:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class JettyServer {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Server server = new Server(8080);

  WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
  context.setResourceBase("../webapp-project/WebContent");
  context.setDescriptor("../webapp-project/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml");
  context.setContextPath("/");
  context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
  server.setHandler(context);

  try {
   server.start();
   server.join();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

On the embedded-jetty project I create a "lib" folder and copy all the libs from the jetty/lib folder, then I add the libs on the Libraries of the project properties.

Running and debugging the jetty embedded works great for me, the jsp and class reloading works like a charm

Comment: Interesting idea.  I used to do something similar to this, but it ended up with my web apps being dependent on jetty, which is something I want to avoid.  Your approach doesn't seem to have this problem, though.  Thanks.

Comment: You could also have this application in test folder, so that it's available for everybody but is not getting into the actual jar file

Answer (score 22):

There's a new (official!) Jetty WTP Plugin supporting Jetty 7.x and 8.x: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin

Comment: I just clicked your link, and it has this update: "Support for this feature has been dropped with Jetty 9. If you feel this should be brought back please file a bug."

Comment: Looks like the new "official" way is to deploy in a standalone Jetty server and use remote debugging: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/debugging-with-eclipse.html

Answer (score 1):

Run-Jetty-Run Eclipse plug-in have well support for both Jetty7 and Jetty 8 , 
and easier to use then WTP Eclipse for me .

It's worth to try it. :)

http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jetty Maven Plugin to configure jetty server in your eclipse very easily. Include the following elements in you `pom.xml`

```
<jetty.version>9.3.0.M1</jetty.version>

<!-- JETTY DEPENDENCIES -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-ant</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and in your pom's plugins managements,

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
       <configuration>
           <stopKey>keyStop</stopKey>
           <stopPort>8181</stopPort>
           <httpConnector>
                 <host>0.0.0.0</host>   //also localhost or IP address
                 <port>8080</port>
           </httpConnector>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or you could separate out the server configuration in separate `jetty-.xml` files. See [Configuring the jetty container](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-jetty-container) for more.

Now right click your maven project and run the goal,

```
mvn jetty:run
```

to start the server on default port 8080. And to stop the server,

```
mvn jetty:stop
```

> If not specified, Jetty will create a ServerConnector instance
>   listening on port `8080`. You can change this default port number by
>   using the system property `jetty.http.port` on the command line, for
>   example, `mvn -Djetty.http.port=9999 jetty:run`.
>   Note that since jetty-9.0 it is no longer possible to configure a
>   https connector directly in the pom.xml: you need to use jetty xml
>   config files to do it.

Read about more goals and configuration on jetty site,

- [Configuring the Jetty Maven Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html)